# How to I get the Buttons to work in fragments?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I have created an app with swipable tabs based on [this Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/). I have added a few TextView and Buttons which do some calculations but I don't know how to get the buttons to work. I don't know much about fragments so please help me with that. I tried to include all all the code in the Main_Activity file but it doesn't work and the app crashes everytime.

Comment: Could you add your classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button add = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSayHi);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edtxtPersonName);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                counter++;
                tv1.setText("Added : " + String.valueOf(counter));

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: No problem..I am glad I was able to help you .. :)